# FOR /F not retrieving all parameters

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set frase=Nome da impressora EPSON L110 Series
REM A linha abaixo ao inves de resultar em "EPSON L110 Series"
REM retorna apenas "EPSON"
REM The line below should return "EPSON L110 Series"
REM instead of only "EPSON"
for /f "tokens=4" %%G IN ("%frase%") DO echo %%G
```

How can I correct this to return all string after "Name of printer"?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `for` line with `for /f "tokens=4*" %%G IN ("%frase%") DO echo %%G %%H` should print the rest of the line. See [For /f - Loop through text | Windows CMD | SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). From that page:

> tokens=3* will process the third token and the 4th + all subsequent
>   items, this can also be written as tokens=3,*
>   ...
>
> %%G is declared in the FOR statement and %%H is implicitly declared
>   via the tokens= option.